# Get the current state of CSS and HTML from the browser

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

There are many times when I make changes to the CSS (and maybe HTML) of different elements directly inside the developer tools. Refreshing the page will result in loss of all those changes and copying them one at a time to a text editor will take a lot of time.

I can directly get the HTML by doing Copy Outer HTML but how do I get all the updated CSS from the page?

I am using Firefox.

Thanks.

Comment: In the Inspector tab, on the far right, there are a number of tabs. One of those is Changes. I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey :)